# Unable to retrieve rss feeds

Tags: php, simplepie

I'm trying to retrieve RSS feeds data from the urls with the below php coding, it returns me the required data like item title,item description, item date etc. But when i try to retrieve the rss feeds data for the below URLS with the same php coding it returns no data. We don't know what is blocking us to retrieve data from below blogs.

Please help us to fix this problem and we can retrieve rss feeds data from the below blog urls.

```
[1] : http://kuwait-music.com

[2] : www.w6n.cc




<?php         
require_once "simplepie.inc";         
$mfeed = [1] :  http://kuwait-music.com;         
$feedinstance = new SimplePie();         
$feedinstance-->set_feed_url($mfeed);         
$feedinstance-->init();         
$feedinstance-->handle_content_type();         
echo $feedinstance-->get_permalink();         
echo $feedinstance-->get_title();          
echo $feedinstance-->get_description();         
$count = 0;            
foreach($feedinstance-->get_items() as $item)    
{            
  echo $item-->get_permalink();            
  echo $item-->get_title();             
  echo $item-->get_description();            
  echo $item-->get_date();           
  $count++;            
  if ($count == 1) break;
}
?>
```

Comment: the two urls for which i can retrieve rss feeds www.q8allinone.com,www.kaifan5.com

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with using SimplePie 1.3, but when I changed the format of the first few lines and added a set_feed_url line for each item, it seemed to work fine.  It works now after this change.